# AS3 thinks e.target.bytesTotal = 0

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I have a very simple preloader for my flash animation and it doenst work when i publish it on FLASH CC. I've already narrowed the problem down and the problem is e.target.bytesTotal
So action script thinks e.target.bytesTotal is 0 when it should be 846kbytes, but i don't know WHY. I tried to publish the swf with COMPRESS = deflate, COMPRESS = LDZ and NO COMPRESS
But it always things e.target.bytesTotal = 0

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

stop();

this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var loaded:Number = e.target.bytesLoaded;
    var total:Number = e.target.bytesTotal;
    var pct:Number = loaded/total;
    loaded_txt.text = String((Math.round(pct * 100)));
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    nextFrame();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bytesLoaded as well as bytesTotal are properties of the ProgressEvent itself.

so changing

```
var loaded:Number = e.target.bytesLoaded;
```

to:

```
var loaded:Number = e.bytesLoaded;
```

should do the trick (same for bytesTotal of course...)